# PGPool II + Django w/ psycopg2 load balancing

Tags: postgresql, python, pgpool, django

I've a pool of applications running django 1.6 with psycopg2 on top of a PGPool II with two backends PostgreSQL servers. But all queries (read and/or write) are going to **master** PostgreSQL even `SELECT`.

As we can see on [PGPool II documentation](http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-load-balancing.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOAD-BALANCING-CONDITION), if we have read queries into transactions we need to hit some conditions to load balancing os send to master. I know that we have some points of the code that we have `SELECT` into a transaction but we also have simple `SELECT` queries which is going to master too.

I'm not sure if, and what, conditions we are hitting to send all queries to master.

Here the table with conditions for load balancing:

[image]